Making some changes to the custom UDF location for WebView2 in a WPF client application. Can I dispose of the browser session?
I am updating the custom UDF location for WebView2 in a WPF client app. When it logs out or closes, can I dispose of the browser session? I reviewed the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder. CoreWebView2Profile.ClearBrowsingDataAsync() isn't supported in our version (1.0.1020.30). I deleted the UDF folder successfully, which is probably not recommended every time. My question is without deleting UDF if I want to clear browsing data , how should I proceed ?
Thanks

I tried using the CoreWebView2Profile.ClearBrowsingDataAsync() method to clear all browsing data, but I guess it is not supported in our WebView2 version 1.0.1020.30.
I managed to delete the UDF folder with the following code, but I understand that deleting the UDF folder is not recommended every time :

My expectation is to understand the right approach which helps us to clear browsing data in WebView2 version 1.0.1020.30

1.0.1020.30 is almost 3 years old. Are you sure this is the version you're referring to? More recent versions have been deprecated due to security issues. You should really update, if that's actually the version in use

Options
To clear browsing data from WebView2 you can:

Use CoreWebView2Profile.ClearBrowsingDataAsync which allows you to more precisely control what you delete from your WebView2 state.
Delete the entire user data folder.
Set IsInPrivateModeEnabled to true to have your WebView2 state cleaned up for you when the WebView2 session ends.
Perhaps find a DevTools Protocol method you can call.

Deleting entire UDF
Deleting the entire user data folder is a fine option as long as you are OK with the following considerations:

You must wait for the WebView2 session to end before the UDF is available to be deleted. Files within the user data folder will be held open by the WebView2 browser process. Until it exits it is unlikely that you will be able to delete the entire user data folder.
There is a slight performance cost to creating a user data folder for the first time. You should measure and ensure the difference is acceptable for your application.

InPrivate
The CoreWebView2ControllerOptions.IsInPrivateModeEnabled property can be set to enable InPrivate mode. This options type is an optional parameter for WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async or if you are directly creating your own CoreWebView2Controller object then you can pass it as an optional parameter to CoreWebView2Environment.CreateCoreWebView2ControllerAsync.
DevTools Protocol
If all else fails, you can check if there is a DevTools Protocol method that will do what you want. You can use coreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync(cdpMethodName, cdpMethodParameters) to invoke a CDP method.
